# folders are hidden when using explorer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We currently have a document library defined on SP2010 with 3 folders (_f1, _f2 and _f3) and a couple of files.
When this library is accessed via Explorer some folders are hidden (_f1, _f2 and forms). The rest of the content appears normally.

As there is no 'hidden' attribute on folders, I am wondering why some folders get flagged as hidden and not some others.

I understand that the forms folder is a system folder and should be hidden. But why are the 3 others behaving differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the underscore character at the beginning of the folder name.